# Count total number of users in Linux (system users not included)

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, unix, virtualbox

[Screenshot of my users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTTOT.jpg)

i am trying to count total amount of users that i created in linux. I found out a script that works, I am using the method if uid is 1000+ then its someone that i created. however it was wrong, my total number of users should be 4 but listed as 5 from this script. I will post a screenshot. I know how to count total users including system users is just: getent passwd | wc -l

```
awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 { C++ } END { print C+0 }' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: You have 5 users with UID >= 1000 in your `passwd` file. The fifth is the special user `nobody` with an UID = 65534. use `; print` command just after `C++` to see them

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please [edit] your question, copy&paste the contents of the input file *as text*  and format it as a code block. See [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @Bodo i did put the code in block tag.

Comment: If you re-read my comment you might find out that I asked for the *input file* which is currently only linked as a screenshot.

Comment: @ArnaudValmary awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 { C++ } PRINT { print C+0 }' /etc/passwd    Like this?

Comment: @Bodo but thats not the input file, its the output file, the result of the script.

Comment: @Svimmel The code clearly shows that `/etc/password` is the input file for the `awk` command. You should copy&paste it *as text*  instead of linking or embedding a screenshot. The output is a number which is mentioned in the text of your question.

Comment: @Bodo i dont think you can copy from Virtualbox terminal shell, that is why i took screenshot, you don't expect me to write all of that  ,do you?                                              and i think you and i have different perspective on input/output is. For me input is something you type, and output is the results of what you typed in. Like in calculator i input 3+3 and the output is 6 for example.

Comment: I don't know if you can copy&paste from your virtual machine, but there are various ways to copy data, e.g. by using a shared folder, network drive or `scp` (or WinSCP). No, you should avoid re-typing your code/data/errors or whatever text belongs to the question because this can introduce or inadvertently fix errors. You ask for help from people that donate their time, so you are responsible to make it easy for us to help you. We cannot copy&paste your screenshot in order to to analyze the problem or to test a proposed solution. Do you expect *us* to re-type your data from a screenshot?

Comment: @Bodo you misunderstood completely. That screenshot is a RESULT not a "script". You can't do anything with it. The code in block you have to copy and paste in linux terminal to get THAT result. You literally misunderstood the question. Why would you copy paste THE RESULT...

Comment: And you, apparently, have not read the text that explains [why you should not upload images of anything that is basically text.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). The file `/etc/password` is an input file for your command, and the screenshot clearly shows something that looks like `/etc/password`. Of course I don't know if it actually shows this file. The main point is that you should copy&paste any text as text, regardless if it is code, input, output, error message or whatever text is related to your question. I downvoted the question now and voted to close it.

Comment: Instead of putting effort on arguing you should improve the question as requested. We could use the contents of *your* file `/etc/passwd` to reproduce the problem and to test a proposed solution. The expectation to provide any text as text is valid for output as well. Of course we can do something with your output: We can use tools like `diff` to compare our output with yours. This may help us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `; print` just after `C++` in order to control which users are concerned by your filter:

```bash
awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 { C++; print } END { print C+0 }' /etc/passwd
```

The output contains:

- `nobody`
- `mahandri`
- `kingfoolish`
- `Benteiversen`
- `Geirgjerde`